# using variables in HtmlXPathSelectors

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am using Scrapy and have run into a few places where it would be nice to use variables, but I can't figure out how. Meaning if I have some long string it would be nice to store it in a variable `long_string` and then select for it: `hxs.select('\\div[@id=long_string]')`.
I'm sure this is supported by Scrapy and I just can't figure it out as it wouldn't make sense for you to always have to hard-code the string in.

Update:
So for the sample text below I want to extract the div where `id="footer"`:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer-menu">
        <div class="region-footer-menu">
            <div id="block-menu-menu-footer-menu" class="block-menu">
                <div class="content">
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li class="first leaf"><a href="/faq" title="">FAQs</a></li>
                        <li class="leaf"><a href="/media" title="">Media</a></li>
                        <li class="leaf"><a href="/partners" title="">Partners</a></li>
                        <li class="last leaf active-trail"><a href="/jobs" title="" class="active-trail active">Jobs</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="block-block-52" class="block block-block">
                <div class="content">
                    <p>SUPPORT</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

We initialize `hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)` for all the below segments.
The following code selects only the first div:
`hxs.select('//div[@id=concat("foot","er")]')`

This code selects nothing but gives no error:
`hxs.select('//div[@id="foot"+"er"]')`

Both of the below code segments select nothing and give no errors:

```
long_string = "foot"
hxs.select('//div[@id=concat(long_string,"er")]')
hxs.select('//div[@id=long_string]')
```

I would like to be able to do either of the bottom two methods and return the desired results.

Comment: Could you post your current spider code and indicate where you'd like to use variables?

Comment: yes, I left out the includes at the top, but if you think they're somehow relevant I'm happy to add them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming + works for string concatenation in Scrapy, this should work:

```
hxs.select('//div[@id="' + long_string + '"]')
```

I'm not familiar with Scrapy, but I don't think you'll be able to select a div that doesn't exist.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question as long_string is a variable which in this example could be storing the string "footer" which exists as the id of the first div.

Comment: The second line is identical to the answer below which doesn't work.

Comment: They're not identical. The other answer had backslashes, which are invalid XPath.

Comment: Do you know why that works and the following doesnt?`hxs.select('//div[@id=long_string]')`

Comment: Yes, because in `hxs.select('//div[@id=long_string]')`, `long_string` is just part of the XPath, so it's treated as an element name just like the `div` there.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried?

```
hxs.select('\\div[@id="' + long_string_variable + '"]')
```

Comment: That gives an invalid syntax error, but I have tried something similar as detailed in my updated post.